# javascript variable name need a increment

Tags: javascript, variables

I found the follow problem, I have that code it is inside a loop.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
requestURL = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/" + deviceID + "/" + getFunc + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;
```

What I need, the variable deviceID need a increment of variable B example:

```
requestURL = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/" + deviceID[B] + "/" + getFunc + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;
```

So deviceID[B] that B is 1 or 2 or 3, because I have variables with the name deviceID1, deviceID2, deviceID3.

Can you help me?

Comment: Use an array instead.

Comment: You can't concatenate a variable name. (You *can*, but it's not a good idea)

Comment: ok I'll replicate the code with the correct name

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to concatenate a variable name, use an array instead:

```
var myArr = [deviceID1, deviceID2, deviceID3];
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    var requestURL = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/" + myArr[i] + "/" + getFunc + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;
}
```

The above is a simple example on how you could use an array.